# How do I register and handle a custom mime type using an existing or custom plugin?

Tags: flash, browser, plugins, browser-plugin

I would like to register for a specific file type to be handled in the browser.

When the browser encounters a custom file type, type xyz, I want the browser to:

1. Use the Flash plugin
2. Pass an existing Flash SWF file to the plugin
3. Then pass the file or url to the swf or be accessible from the swf

How do I accomplish this?

Here is what I've [read](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) about it so far.

Comment: It sounds very unlikely that there would be a genereic cross-browser way to do this, or indeed *any* way that doesn't require building a plugin. Without focus on a specific browser this looks too broad to work on SO

Comment: Why are people so anxious to mark posts too broad or opinion based?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the wet dream of those "0-Day Vulnerability" creating scums. Anyways its likely impossible since Flash Plugin + Browser  do not work in the manner you describe.

**Simple answer : You can't do this!!** In a browser the SWF must always be embeded inside an HTML if you're want to pass additional data to it. Otherwise some button is needed in the U.I (user selects a saved file).

**LONG VERSION (with possible solution)...**
The logic is do-able with say, VLC Plugin cos that's one complete app for handling media files so just associate media format with it, Flash Plugins is different cos it just works like an operating system inside browser (only operating SWF files as *Flash OS* apps). Which specific SWF will handle that format...?

**But I have a specific SWF to handle format XYZ?**
Yeah well in the browser, you have to **embed** the swf inside an html file that exists on a server. What do you expect the AS3 code in that embeded SWF to know about a file link that was clicked on a random webpage somewhere out there in this universe?

**Ok, what about that possible solution?**
If this was my problem, I would just make where the page `href=` normally links to format .xzy, that would instead...

- open a new tab to the hosted SWF **plus** url to file.xyz. The address bar would look like :  `src="http://mySWFserver/SWFembeded.html?link="www.myStorage.com/File.xyz"`
- Your embeded SWF simply **[reads the address
  bar](http://snipplr.com/view/47055/get-url-of-the-page-where-swf-is-embedded/)**,
  parses the URL pointing to file.xyz
- Then a `URLStream` loads the file bytes to be handled by other
  functions in the SWF.

Of course you don't have to open a new tab. Simply embed hosted SWF on that same html page. New tab is just easier for end-user to understand that an external format was opened and handled separately to this main page,